# Date is not pass in function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with jQuery. I have created an AJAX function as following :

```
$.ajax({
        url : '<?php echo base_url()."admin/utilities/get_project" ?>',
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(responce){

            var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
            var firstDate = new Date(responce[0].start_date);
            var secondDate = new Date(responce[0].deadline);

            var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay)));

            /*=========================================*/
            $(".fc-day").each(function(){
                var d = $(this).data('date');

                if(d >= responce[0].start_date && d < responce[0].deadline)
                {
                    if(d == responce[0].start_date)
                    {
                        //$(this).html("<a href='#' onclick = 'init_task_modal("+responce[0].id+"); return false' class='fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-resizable nisarg' style='background-color:#b72974;border-color:#b72974'><span class='fc-title'>"+responce[0].name+"</span></a>");
                        $(this).append("<a href='#' onclick = 'get_task_name("+responce[0].id+","+d+");' class='fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-resizable nisarg' style='background-color:#b72974;border-color:#b72974'><span class='fc-title'>"+responce[0].name+"</span></a>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $(this).append("<a href='#' class='fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-resizable' style='background-color:#b72974;border-color:#b72974'><span class='fc-title'>&nbsp;</span></a>");                            
                    }
                }   
            });
        }
    });
```

Here, in **get_task_name()** I have passed the project id and date. So I have created a function as :

```
function get_task_name(project_id,tdate)
{
    alert(project_id);
    alert(tdate);
}
```

In this function I got project id but date is not coming. The **tdate** displays as **1980**. And in the function it is passed as **2016-07-20**.

So how can I get proper date value in my function ?

Comment: If you do `console.log(d)` after this line `var d = $(this).data('date');` what does it show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `onclick` property is a bad idea in the first place, but trying to write that function by concatenating strings together is a worse idea.

Do this instead:

```
$("<a href='#' class='fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-resizable nisarg' style='background-color:#b72974;border-color:#b72974'><span class='fc-title'>" + responce[0].name + "</span></a>").appendTo(this).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    get_task_name( responce[0].id, d );
});
```